# What would the URL be for a second website/store?

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to setup a second, separate website/store which does not share the same shopping cart. How do I do that, and how would the new website/store be accessed?
Single domain/server.

i.e. the shopping carts need to be separate because the origin locations for shipping are different.

Answer (score 1):

You will be setting up a new Website (store group) and Store View (store), because shipping origin can only be set at the Global/Default and Website levels:

[image: Screenshot of admin setting for shipping origin]

URL settings live in **System > Configuration > Web**, and there are three options for how you things up:

1. **Different Base URLs**: You can set a separate URL in the Base URL settings (**Unsecure** & **Secure** panels) at either the new Website or new Store View scope.
2. You can set Magento to add the store scope to the end of the Base URL (**URL Options** panel - changing this will require a reindex).
3. Change nothing.

So, now that you know your options, let's look at the options you have for site behavior:

1) For different Base URLs, you can detect the `HTTP_HOST` header and set the appropriate store view or website code. NB: this is "above" Magento at the webserver configuration level and therefore has no admin interface. Let's say your main URL is **jeff.com** and your other URL is **jeff2.com**: the proper scope will be loaded for a first-time visitor based on the URL they used to access your sole installation.

2) If you go the add-the-store-code route, then all users will end up on the default store and would have to either click a link to load the other store and/or use the store switcher block to select a different store scope. For an example of this store selector block, see the upper left of the [Magento demo site](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/) (pic below for posterity - the demo example switches locales, but these are done through store scopes.):

[image]

The nice thing about having a user access the store switching URL (query string of `___store=[code]`) is that Magento will set a store cookie for that user, and their selection will "stick" between visits.

3) If you choose to have no differences, then you will need to present the user with `___store=[code]` links or have them use the store switcher.

Of course, you can also do other tricks to set the desired store scope based on geoIP lookup by your webserver, and there are lots of other options which are variations on this theme. Hopefully this broad explanation of the essential options will help you make a more informed decision.

Comment: I tried setting up a new web,store and store view named veneercat but url takes me to the main store. https://ro.overstockstone.com/s/?___store=veneercat/ at this point I'll probably just have to create another entire magento install to make it work. their docs are worthless, never use magento again in the future

Comment: Well, 200k+ stores should let you know that at least *some* people have found the software to be usable... This is basic functionality which works out of the box. What are the expected differences between the different store views?

Comment: I need a separate store, different categories i the sidebar menu, separate shopping cart so customer can't put items from both stores into 1 cart. That's it. The origin zip I already figured out how to override in my shipping module

Comment: Different categories = new Root Category + new "Store Name" (store group). Separate cart = associate products with one website or another.

Comment: i did all that, but what is the url to pull it up?

Comment: It depends on your store code - you just need the `___store=store_code` GET param.